# SlickGrid multiSelect="false" does not disable keyboard multi selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid in my project, and I want to use it's multi selection disabling option. My problem is, that the multiSelect="false" works for stopping mouse multi selection, but I can select multiple rows using SHIFT + Arrow key combination.

Do you have any simple (built in) solution to disable arrow key multi selection too, or do I have to do it in the onSelectedRowsChanged event?

Thank you.

Comment: Can I see your code in a fiddle? I've done a test in wich it seems to work

Comment: My project is to complex to put it into jsfiddle, but I'm creating an example soon.

Comment: thanks, put just the relevant part

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8TWEm/50/
The multiSelect: false option disables SHIFT + mouse, and CTRL + mouse, but SHIFT + Arrow keys remains enabled.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell, that it is not Column selection, but row selection.

Comment: I've answered.. let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after much searching I found this [bug](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/379) in the library in the ***slick.rowselectionmodel.js*** file

read and add this lines in handleKeyDown function

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
      if (!_grid.getOptions().multiSelect) {
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Can it be somehow merged into the main SlickGrid repo (I think about pull request here)? Because I am using bower in my project, and I would not want to hack the code in this way.

Comment: Why don't you have a local copy of the script??

Comment: Actually we are using slickgrid at my workplace, and it's not safe to rely on a local copy (Anyone could update the script, and so the local changes are lost).

Comment: @gsanta source control is your friend.

Comment: @gsanta  I think it's safer put your scripts in a local server rather than on the web, if someone change the scripts or remove them?

Comment: Okey, you are right. I just somehow don't feel safe to modify third party codes. But I can live with that now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a safer option, use jquery's `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` function when you bind to SlickGrid's keyboard events, such that SlickGrid will later be notified that event propagation shall stop.

Example code:

```
grid.onKeyDown.subscribe((e, args) => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return;
});
```

Read more about this function here: https://api.jquery.com/event.isImmediatePropagationStopped/